# cordova cli commands fail on ios: ENOENT cordova-config.json.SOME_NUMBER

Tags: ios, cordova

When running cordova commands I started getting this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/johnny/.config/configstore/cordova-config.json.1603791664' -> '/Users/johnny/.config/configstore/cordova-config.json'
```

Tried reinstalling node, npm, cordova-cli.

Answer (score 13):

Solved it by creating the file `cordova-config.json` with the content: `{}`

Comment: so elegant, so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by deleting the `configstore` folder