# Can't set up cordova for android

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins

I just installed cordova in my computer in order to make android apps using javascript.

I ran this command after i created my project on D:\learn_cordova\firstApp :

```
cordova platform add android
```

The result was the following :

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.ignacio.firstApp
        Name: HelloWorld
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-28
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@8.1.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android
```

Everything looks correct, but when i run `cordova requirements` in order to see what else do i need in order to make my first android app i get this result :

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT Error output:
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Gradle: installed C:\gradle\bin\gradle
Some of requirements check failed
```

AS it says android is not recognized as a command, i tried adding variables to PATH :

```
C:\Users\ignac\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
C:\Users\ignac\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

There is supposed to exist the `C:\Users\ignac\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools`  folder according to this

[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350692/android-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) however that was written back in 2012.

When I type `android` in cmd returns that the command does not exist

Prior to this, when running  `cordova platform list` I   was getting an error about an inexistent file called

```
C:\Users\ignac\.config\configstore\cordova-config.json
```

And I saw a  [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502489/cordova-cli-commands-fail-on-ios-enoent-cordova-config-json-some-number) which indicated that creating the file with '{}' as input should fix
the problem, so i did that.

Comment: Your link clearly states C:\Users\Parag Jain\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
C:\Users\Parag Jain\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools but you didn't do that

Comment: As I mentioned in the question section, the 'tools' folder didn't exist, so I downloaded it from somewhere else and put it in the correct place, after deleting all of the path variables I created and creating new ones, I was able to build the apk, however i am still unable to run the emulator. When i open android studio & try to run an emulation it tells me that there is an error with my ANDROID_SDK_ROOT path variable